# Lubuntu 17.10 software update and repository add problem

Tags: updates, lubuntu, 17.10, update-manager

I had Lubuntu 17.04 installed and when I wanted to upgrade to 17.10 version there was some problems.

Finally I solved the problem by disabling all repositories and now I have Lubuntu 17.10. but I have a new problem.

- First: I have disabled all repositories and it is not possible to enable theme from software & update settings. When I try to mark a theme to enable, nothing happens!
- Second: when I use `sudo apt-get update` I have the following output that does not seems good:

  ```
  Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease         
  Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
  Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [78.6 kB]      
  Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful Release     
    404  Not Found
  Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72.2 kB]
  Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78.6 kB]
  Reading package lists... Done                                 
  E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
  N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
  N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
  ```

**Question update:**

out put from `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` is :

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to

# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful universe multiverse main restricted #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates universe multiverse main restricted #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
## deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
## deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe multiverse main restricted #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
# deb http://cran.um.ac.ir/bin/linux/ubuntu artful/
# deb-src http://cran.um.ac.ir/bin/linux/ubuntu artful/
# deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
# deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
# deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
deb https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/
deb-src https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner

deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ artful main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ artful main
```

but `sudo apt-get update` still has following result :

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease         
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease                
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease              
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful Release           
  404  Not Found
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease               
Hit:7 https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/ InRelease             
Hit:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful InRelease                
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

where can I fix :

```
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful Release           
      404  Not Found
```

I can't find it in my `sources.list`

Comment: I grabbed your first PPA and opened http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ in a browser... A quick scan showed it supports  xenial (16.04), trusty (14.04) and other versions - but I don't see support for yaketty (17.04) or artful (17.10).  So the error is valid  (check wherever you got it from & you'll probably note its for xenial/trusty/....)

Comment: You provided minimal info on theme (no name, no source (where it came from) etc so I'm ignoring it. Themes I've liked I save locally, and learnt that as software updates they won't always work (LXDE was GTK+2 which was really old - its updated slowly then started moving towards LxQt which is very different so I would expect them to drop certain GTK+ things.. but this is opinion as I don't use LXDE much & thus don't follow happenings there)  Again I'd check where you got the theme from, and what versions (Glib/GTK+.. if not Lubuntu versions) it was for

Comment: Check files under the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` there You can find additional repository files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your repository's here :

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**You should remove the repo from Ubuntu wine(what you got).**

Save and exit the file.

**Add this repo for Ubuntu wine.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Or this one :

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I used `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` but there was not any link for wine in the list. and there are a lot of inactive links (starting with #)